# Applying CAP theorem for Dropbox.com

Tags: dropbox, distributed-system, cap-theorem

As per the definition of [CAP theorem](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCYQFjACahUKEwjG9MWa-unIAhVIwWMKHXAJDfY&url=https%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FCAP_theorem&usg=AFQjCNGsTwPR6-wJgM3YK5RUexKNM5I6GQ&sig2=a_c37mNgvpWYSrfEXZe9xg), there can be only 2 conditions satisfied by any distributed system. 
Logically thinking, I feel that a cloud service like Dropbox will satisfy C,P at a time. 
C such that even if you update the data in one node, the data will be replicated to the other node immediately.

The correct answer is P,A (Partition Tolerance and availability).
Now can a cloud service be both P&A at a time ?

Any insights on this ?
Thanks :)